# NginX Configuration Downloading index.php

Tags: php, nginx, dns

I have the following nginx configurations.

**mydomain.com** */etc/nginx/sites-available/default*

*DNS Settings - Record Type:ANAME, Name:@, IP:1.2.3.4*

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/html/mydomain/public;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

**stats.mydomain.com** */etc/nginx/sites-available/piwik*

*DNS Settings - Record Type:ANAME, Name:stats, IP:1.2.3.4*

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name stats.mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/piwik;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

My primary domain works perfectly and processes the php correctly. However, my subdomain displays the raw code/index.php in the browser.

What am I missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're missing the `location /` block that you have on `mydomain.com` and that you don't have at subdomain which is responsible for trying to "hit" the `index.php` of `php-fpm`.

Comment: @Mjh Thanks. I have updated the location on stats.mydomain.com and the  server_name on mydomain.com. Unfortunately, still no luck. Now both redirect to /var/www/html/mydomain/public.

Comment: That would indicate that `/etc/nginx/sites-available/piwik` is not being read by `nginx`. Does `nginx.conf` `include` files from a `sites-enabled` directory - and have you installed a symlink for `piwik`?

Comment: @Richard Smith You beauty! Had to create SymLink in site-available and remove duplicate listen [::].

Comment: Can you answer question, so that I can accept answer. Thank you.